# stopping black x when retrieving profile pic, not filling in details

Tags: javascript, user-profile, user-profile-service

I have a page in which I am getting a profile pic from mysites. It asks for the password and when you fill in the details it does what its supposed to and the profile pic appears. However when you press cancel the black cross appears. How can I make it so, it just shows the default image that is there before inputting any information.
Here is my code:

```
myImage = MyProperties.get_pictureUrl(),


if(myImage!=null){
    jQuery("#profileImage").attr("src", myImage);
}
```

Comment: How the default image is set?

Comment: normal html <img src= />

Comment: Where it is stored?

Comment: in a library on my sharepoint site.

Comment: What is the URL stored in "myImage"? What is the URL of your MySite? What is the URL of the site hosting your page?

Answer (score 0):

Update the function where you are trying to set the profile image.

Add a try block around the read profile pic code. Inside the catch set profile pic to default.